# find & update distinct object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, servicenow

I have resulted array of objects after gliderecord from a table.

i need to update all the resulted record's field status to permanently failed.
& after updating all of them.

i need to find out all latest of the duplicate objects & update them again to ready status

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('table');
gr.addQuery('filter');
gr.query();
var Arr=[];
while(gr.next()){
Arr.push(gr);
gr.status = 'permanently failed';

// after updating all the records status to permanently failed.
//need to compare with object's "object id" field & if any duplicate object is found keep the latest updated one 
//after all the filtered array of objects need to again update the status to ready .

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You think you have an array of objects, but you don't. What you have instead is an array with a bunch references to the same object. When you call `gr.next()` you are updating the contents of the object `gr`. When you get to the end of the loop, your array will contain a bunch of references to `gr`, and `gr` will contain the contents of the last record processed.

In order to create an array of objects, you need to create a new object each time through the loop. You need to do something like this:

```
while (gr.next()) {
    var obj = {
        sys_id: gr.getValue('sys_id'), 
        status: gr.getValue('status')
    };
    Arr.push(obj);
}
```